# Other then cache what are the on chip memory? And how explicitly can be addressable?

Tags: cpu-cache

I came to understanding about SRAM as on chip memory. Moving towards latest technologies High Band width another on-chip memory? Also I need to know what are the latest tech used in processors, in terms of on-chip memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of information about CPU cache in paper titled [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory, written by Ulrich Drepper](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Elstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf). Especially in sections 2.1.1 and whole 3.
If you are interested in current technologies, you should read available documentation and optimisation guides for modern processors. You can find many details about processors at wikichip.org, for example https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2.

In case of AMD/Intel processors search for "AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual " or "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual".